# How to create projectile that will move with constant speed along curved path?

Tags: math, sfml, game-development

I'm making a little game using SFML. I made a turret which shoots in 4 directions (diagonally) and now I'm trying to figure out how to shoot out the projectiles. I want them to travel from point A (turret) to point B (enemy) along curved path with constant speed and I don't really know what calculations and formulas should I used to control x and y position of the projectile. I'm terrible at explaining but maybe a photo will make it clearer:
[Sketch of a turret with enemies and curved paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3wv8.jpg)

I tried finding quadratic equations and equations of circles and move the projectiles along them. The problem was that:

- firstly, my calculations weren't accurate
- secondly, due to how cirlces and parabolas are calculated the speed of the projectile wasn't constant at all...

Comment: Working with quadratic equations will give you non-uniform projectile speed. However, working with circles might be more promising. Try subdividing the circle into equally sized sectors. Then using trigonometry to compute the (x,y) of each point along the circumference. Check out this diagram I made.

https://share.sketchpad.app/22/c32-0e0f-afbc13.jpeg